Limit lifting property of the functor $Grp(C) \to C$
Let $C$ be any category with finite products. Then we can define the category of group objects $Grp(C)$.
Since group objects are just objects with additional structure, we have a forgetful functor $\mathbb U : Grp(C) \to C$.
I believe we have the following for any (small) diagram $D : I \to Grp(C)$:
$\lim (\mathbb UD)$ exists in $C$ $\iff$ $\lim D$ exists in $Grp(C)$. Moreover, if any of these limits exist, then $\mathbb U(\lim D) \simeq \lim(\mathbb UD)$
I believe this means precicely that $\mathbb U$ lifts and preserves limits.
Is the above statement correct? If it is, can you provide any references for the above claim?
I tried to look everywhere, but I was unable to find a reference for this statement.

I believe that I have a proof for the lifting property of $\mathbb U$. Would you please check if it is correct?
Claim: $\mathbb U$ lifts limits.
We have a fully faithful functor $Y_{Grp} : Grp(C) \to Grp^{C^{op}}$. Let $U : Grp \to Set$ be the forgetful functor, and let $C_U : Grp^{C^{op}} \to Set^{C^{op}}$ be the post-composition functor with $U$, $F \mapsto UF$. Let $Y$ be the Yoneda-embedding $C \to Set^{C^{op}}$.
Then we have the following commutaive diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Grp(C) @>{Y_{Grp}}>> Grp^{C^{op}};\\
@V{\mathbb U}VV @V{C_U}VV \\
C @>{Y}>> Set^{C^{op}};
\end{CD}$$
Note that here $F$ is in the essential image of $Y_{Grp}$ if and only if $C_U(F)$ is in the essential image of $Y$. I.e. the group-valued functors that come from group objects are precisely the functors that are representable.
Now to the proof:
Let $D : I \to Grp(C)$ be a small diagram. We need to prove the following: if $\lim (\mathbb UD)$ exists, then so does $\lim D$, and $\mathbb U(\lim D) \simeq \lim(\mathbb UD)$.
As $Grp$ is complete, so is $Grp^{C^{op}}$, so $\lim(Y_{Grp}D)$ exists. Now limits in $Grp^{C^{op}}$ and $Set^{C^{op}}$ are both calculated "object-wise"; moreover $U : Grp\to Set$ preserves limits, hence $C_U$ preserves limits as well.
We obtain $C_U(\lim Y_{Grp}D) = \lim(C_UY_{Grp}D)$. By our assumption, $\lim (\mathbb UD)$ exists, hence (since $Y$ preserves limits) $\lim(C_UY_{Grp}D) = \lim (Y\mathbb UD) = Y \lim(\mathbb UD)$.
Then by the note above, $\lim (Y_{Grp}D)$ is in the essential image of $Y_{Grp}$. Let $L$ be an object s.t. $Y_{Grp}(L) = \lim (Y_{Grp}D)$. As $Y_{Grp}$ is fully faithful, the morphisms in the cone of $\lim (Y_{Grp}D)$ have (unique) preimages in $Grp(C)$, let these be $p_i : L \to D(i)$ (where $i \in I$).
Now it remains to show that $(L; p_i \, : \, i \in I)$ is a limit cone of $D$, and that $\mathbb U(L) \simeq \lim(\mathbb UD)$. The first statement is immediate, as fully faithful functors reflect limits.
The second statement:
$
\begin{gather*}
Y\mathbb U(L) \simeq C_UY_{Grp}(L) \simeq C_U(\lim(Y_{Grp}D) \simeq \lim(C_UY_{Grp}D) \simeq \\ \simeq\lim(Y\mathbb U D) \simeq Y(\lim(\mathbb UD))
\end{gather*}
$
But $Y$ is fully faithful, hence reflects isomorphisms. We obtain $\mathbb U(L) \simeq \lim(\mathbb UD)$.
